# How to display timestamps in a Vue.js/Firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

I am attempting to build a Vue.js/Firebase chat app based on the following repo: https://github.com/jsfanatik/vuestacks-chat-vue-firebase. I have set up the Chat component to enable the pushing of inputted messages into firestore, then return the messages to the template via a `getMessage()` method. The `getMessage()` method returns all of the message content to the screen, including the name of the logged-in user, the message content, and the timestamp reformatted with moment.js. The problem with the repo is that as soon as a new message is added, the timestamps on all the other messages will re-render to reflect the timestamp of the most recent message. I thought that the issue would lie in the `getMessage()` method:

```
    async getMessage () {
      let snapshot = await db.collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp').get()
      const messages = []
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let appData = doc.data()
        appData.id = doc.id
        appData.timestamp = moment(doc.timestamp).format('lll')
        messages.push(appData)
      })
      this.messages = messages
    },
```

...but I'm not sure how to reconfigure this method in order to fix that issue. Any idea how to get each message to maintain it's own timestamp, and not that of the current message? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert [Firestore Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#toDate()) to Javascript Date before using it with moment js

```
appData.timestamp = moment(appData.timestamp.toDate()).format('lll')
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work though:( I then tried adding different configurations of that line, like this: ```appData.timestamp = moment(doc.timestamp).toDate().format('lll')```, but that also didn't work. I'm getting error messages that say: ```Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined```. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 You need to do `appData.timestamp = moment(appData.timestamp.toDate()).format('lll')` and not `moment(doc.timestamp).format('lll')` since `appData = doc.data()`. `doc` is a snapshot. *(answer adapted)*

Answer (score 0):

Firebase timestamp can be rendered as milliseconds since the epoch which can be used in the moment constructor

```
moment(doc.timestamp.toMillis()).format('lll')
```